# need help changing logitech script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

i have this script that want to change capslock button to on/off without holding lctrl to activate. Who can help me? Thank you everyone

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsModifierPressed("lctrl") then
        repeat  
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    PressMouseButton(1)
                    Sleep(15)
                    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end             
        until not IsModifierPressed("lctrl")
    end         
end
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What part did you get stuck on? We're not just going to do the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the game, in the "Controls Settings", introduce alternative key for "Shoot" action.
   (I assume your game allows binding two different keys for the same action)
   For example, let it be keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   So, now in the game you can shoot either using Left Mouse Button or using Keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   Of course, you will use LMB for manual shooting as usually, but your GHub script will use <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Try to play the game with both LMB and <kbd>P</kbd> for shooting.
   Make sure you can shoot with <kbd>P</kbd> key while keeping LMB pressed.
   (Some games do not allow this)
3. The script

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
      repeat
         PressAndReleaseKey("P")
         Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
   end
end
```